# Using a shared array in Message Passing Interface

Tags: mpi

I would like to use a shared array in an MPI program such that after one process finishes its work, it will put its rank into that array and "update" it by sending it to others without waiting. I tried MPI_Bcast by giving it as "root" parameter the rank of the running process (instead of 0), but when I display the array from each process, it only shows that changes occurred locally (other ranks sent are not in the array).

```
int array[10];
array[rank] = rank;
MPI_Bcast(array,10,MPI_INT,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("%d, %d - ",array[0],array[1]); //displays: 0, 26872 - 32678, 1
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you place a code?

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and put it there. Thank you!

Comment: Please update your code to a [Minimal, complete and varifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can run and debug your code. Things that are missing: Which ranks execute the code fragment? All of them? One of them?

Comment: There will be race conditions. You are broadcasting the array to all processes, but the state of the array is different for each process. For the second process, array looks like [0, 1, ....], the third one like [0, 0, 2,  ....] etc. Depending on which one is broadcast and received whenever, the result is undefined.

Comment: @wak, how exactly could there be race conditions? Blocking MPI broadcasts are collective - all ranks in the communicator must explicitly participate in the broadcast, must specify the same value for the root rank, and make consecutive collective calls in the same sequence as all other ranks do.

Answer (score 2):

Typing `int array[10];` in the main of a MPI program does not generate a shared array. Each process handle its own version of the array. `MPI_Bcast()` has been designed as a way for a given process `root` to broadcast its version of the array to all other processes. Thus, the initial version of the array on all other processes is erased.

`MPI_Bcast()` is a collective operation: every processes of the communicator must call `MPI_Bcast()` using the same `root`. The count and type can be different, but the amount of data sent by the root must be equal to the amount received by all processes.

Two options to solve your problem:

- The function that you are looking for may be [`MPI_Allgather()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Allgather.3.php). See [these schemes](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/): `MPI_Allgather()` can be used to synchronize a global array after modifications by local process. The global array is not "shared", because each process uses a different space in memory, but values of different processes will be similar after a call to `MPI_Allgather()`.
- You are looking for a real shared array.Such an array can be allocated by calling [`MPI_Win_allocate_shared()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/current/man3/MPI_Win_allocate_shared.3.php). See the [version 3.1 of the MPI standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), paragraph 11.2.3 Window That Allocates Shared Memory on page 407. In  particular, attention must be paid to the following warning if you are running programs using multiple nodes of a cluster:

  > It is the user’s responsibility to ensure that the communicator comm represents a group of processes that can create a shared memory segment that can be accessed by all processes in the group.

  You can find and an example of `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()` [there](http://meetings.mpi-forum.org/secretary/2011/07/slides/allocate_shared_slides.pdf)

In the following example, I will assume that you are interrested in the first option. It is compiled by `mpicc main.c -o main` and ran by `mpirun -np 42 main`.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int  size, rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);    


    int* array=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    if(array==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}

    //modifying the local portion of the array
    array[rank]=rank;

    //gather content from each process and broadcast it to all processes
    MPI_Allgather(&array[rank],1,MPI_INT,array,1,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //each process has its own copy of the array, but the values are the same.
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(i==rank){
            printf("rank %d got ",rank);
            for(j=0;j<size;j++){
                printf("%d ",array[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    free(array);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Francis, thanks a lot for your response! Since yesterday, I am now more interested in the second option because the first one is blocking and in my case, I really don't want it to be: [here's what I really want to accomplish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208229/mpi-process-helping-another-one-when-it-finishes-its-work)