# MPI: Process helping another one when it finishes its work

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

Here's my problem:

Given an initial interval [a,b] to parallelize & supposing that there are processes faster than others, I would like to make a process i go "help" another one (j) when it finishes its chunk (work), helping in this case means dividing equally the chunk of process j (the one that's still working) between it & process i (the one that's going to help). I've got the idea of this algorithm but I don't know how to use MPI communication functions (such as Broadcast, Allgather, send, recv) to implement it: I would like to use an array "arr" shared by all processes & which size's equals the number of all processes. arr[i] = 1 means that process i has finished working, otherwise it's equal to -1. I initialize all its elements to -1, when a process of rank "rank" finishes its work, it does arr[rank] = 1 & keeps waiting for a working process to notice it & send it a new chunk. Here's a "pseudo-code" of what I would like to achieve:

```
MPI_Init ( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nb_proc );

int i;
int a = 0, b = max; //initial interval [a,b] to parallelize
int j; arr[nb_proc];

for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    arr[j] = -1; //initially, all processes are working
}

do
{
    i = a + rank;
    do
    {
        if(there's a free process) // checking the array "arr" & finding at least one element that equals 1
        {
            //Let that process be process of rank "r":
            arr[r] = -1;
            int mid = (b+i)/2; //dividing the rest of the work
            a = mid + rank - r;
            MPI_Send(a to process r);
            MPI_Send(b to process r);
            b = a-1;
        }

        /*does i-th iteration*/

        i = i + p;
    }
    while(i <= b);
    arr[rank] = 1; //finished working and about to start waiting for new work
}
while(there's at least one process that's still working & if it's the case get the new work (starting a & finishing b) from it);

MPI_Finalize ( );
return 0;
```

My main problem concerns the way to access to the array and how to be sure it's updated to all processes and that all processes have the same array at an instant t. I would appreciate your help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737545/mpi-with-c-passive-rma-synchronization) is about a problem similar to yours and it should give you an idea how your algorithm could be implemented in MPI. Note though that it goes well beyond the classical send/receive operations and involves an often poorly implemented part of the MPI standard.

Comment: If one process is already working on a task then another process trying to join in to help is going to be ... , well, it's going to need some very tricky programming for a task to be decomposed at an arbitrary point during its execution so that it can be continued by two processes.  I think a better approach would be to initially create many small tasks, each to be worked on by one process at a time.  When a process finishes a task it picks up the next unstarted task.  This approach to load-balancing is widely implemented and relatively easy to design and program.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. In my case, I kind of do this, except that a small task in my case is an iteration, so I don't see how dividing initially the interval to many small tasks could help my case knowing that if I do this, I will also need to know which tasks are still available and therefore need some type of synchronization and shared structure between processes... Could you please tell me how I can proceed ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't really have anything to add, let me restate what I've already suggested:  Investigate the *master/worker* design pattern for parallel program structuring.  Create tasks for the workers which are small enough, and numerous enough, that your computation takes care of load balancing automatically.  Avoid trying to join processes to an already-executing computation.

Comment: To my mind the suggestion of @HighPerformanceMark is the good one. Think about your workplace. Once you have finished your job, you report back to your boss (often called "root process") and the boss gives you some work to do. The job of the boss is to divide the big project into small tasks and delegate these tasks to the workers. The task must be small enough so that the workers can finish them in a reasonable time and large enough so that reporting does not become the major task. Would you ask all your co-workers if they can share their task with you? What would happen in large companies?

Comment: @francis Hi again, thanks a lot for taking time to help me. I know it's a good idea but there's a problem: I don't know how to centralize the work set (set of small tasks) in the master process so that the workers poll him everytime they finish with one set of tasks to ask for more work... Maybe a shared memory ?